# How can I compute the cumulative points?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
HomeTeam = ["A", "B", "B", "D", "C", "A", "C", "D"]
AwayTeam = ["C", "D", "A", "C", "B", "D", "A", "B"]
Result = ["HT", "AT", "HT", "HT", "D", "AT", "D", "AT"]
Round = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]

dict = {'HomeTeam': HomeTeam, 'AwayTeam': AwayTeam, 'Result': Result, 'Round': Round}  

df = pd.DataFrame(dict) 

df
```

[image]

Where Result: 
"HT" = HomeTeam won --> HomeTeam +3, AwayTeam 0 
"AT" = AwayTeam won --> HomeTeam 0, AwayTeam +3 
"D" = It's a draw --> HomeTeam +1, AwayTeam +1

I need to create two different columns: 
1) **Cumulative Points Home Team**: it contains the total points obtained from the Home team until that match. 
2) **Cumulative Points Away Team**: it contains the total points obtained from the Away team until that match.

I'm using `Python`, but my loop doesn't work perfectly.

**This is my expected result:**

[image]

Comment: can you share your code, and also ur expected output.

Comment: Do you want to include the current match in the cumulative point count?

Comment: *my loop doesn't work perfectly* - can you include this loop in the question?

Comment: If the home team is A for example, do you want to include the points of A Until that match? Or do you simply want to know how many points you have earned at home until that date regardless of the team? could you show the expected output? for this DataFrame

Comment: I've just updated my answer with the expected result, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution without loops and flexible purely with Pandas**

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) with [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) (to get the Points) and [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table) 
to return the frame to the original sape:

```
df = df.join(df.reset_index()
               .melt(['index','Round','Result'],value_name = 'Team',var_name = 'H/A')
               .sort_values('index')
               .assign(Points = lambda x:np.select([ x['Result'].eq('D'),
                                                     x['H/A'].eq('HomeTeam')
                                                             .mul(x['Result'].eq('HT'))|
                                                     x['H/A'].eq('AwayTeam')
                                                             .mul(x['Result'].eq('AT'))],
                                                    [1,3],
                                                    default = 0))
               .assign(CumPoints = lambda x: x.groupby('Team')
                                              .Points
                                              .cumsum()
                                              .groupby(x['Team'])
                                              .shift(fill_value = 0))
               .pivot_table(index = 'index',
                            columns = 'H/A',
                            values = 'CumPoints'
                            fill_value = 0)
               .sort_index(axis = 1,ascending = False)
               .add_prefix('CumulativePoints')

            )
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  HomeTeam AwayTeam Result  Round  CumulativePointsHomeTeam  CumulativePointsAwayTeam
0        A        C     HT      1                         0                         0 
1        B        D     AT      1                         0                         0 
2        B        A     HT      2                         0                         3 
3        D        C     HT      2                         3                         0 
4        C        B      D      3                         0                         3 
5        A        D     AT      3                         3                         6 
6        C        A      D      4                         1                         3 
7        D        B     AT      4                         9                         4
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your code:

```
cpts ={'A':0,'B':0,'C':0,'D':0}

cpts_ht = []
cpts_at = []
for i in range(len(df.Result)):
    cpts_ht.append(cpts[df.HomeTeam[i]])
    cpts_at.append(cpts[df.AwayTeam[i]])

    if df.Result[i]=='HT':
        cpts[df.HomeTeam[i]]+=3
    elif df.Result[i]=='AT':
        cpts[df.AwayTeam[i]]+=3
    else:
        cpts[df.HomeTeam[i]]+=1
        cpts[df.AwayTeam[i]]+=1

df['cummulative_home'] = cpts_ht
df['cummulative_away'] = cpts_at

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  HomeTeam AwayTeam Result  Round  cummulative_home  cummulative_away
0        A        C     HT      1                 0                 0
1        B        D     AT      1                 0                 0
2        B        A     HT      2                 0                 3
3        D        C     HT      2                 3                 0
4        C        B      D      3                 0                 3
5        A        D     AT      3                 3                 6
6        C        A      D      4                 1                 3
7        D        B     AT      4                 9                 4
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but the final results don't match with the expected one. The problem is that HomeTeam and AwayTeam change each match

Comment: Check the edited answer, feel free to comment if you've any queries.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped. It helps the community at large in recognizing the correct answer. You can do that by clicking the tick mark next the answer.Cheers.